# what will happen if file not exist

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to access the file that does not exist. what error will it throw.?

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    // read from file or write to file
}
```

What will happen if file not exist.?

Comment: Try it and see what error you get.. You forgot c#-5.0 tag

Comment: What did you see when you looked at [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx)? Stack Overflow is *not* an alternative to research.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/47ek66wy(v=vs.110).aspx) opening file when file is non existant throws [FileNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Therefore to make it work do this :

```
var fileName = "c:\file.txt";
if(File.Exists(fileName)
{
      using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
      //code
}
```

or even :

```
try{
   using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Open))
      {
      //code
      }
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e)
{
      //code
}
```

Because of my hatred for people commenting like "google it!" "look it up in documentation" I decided to answer this question despite that it is typical documentation search. Stack should be about question-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to above answer It may throw [UnauthorizedAccessException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx) too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.